# Understanding malloc()

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

```
void fillArray(int* array, int len) {
    printf("Filling an array at address %p with %d "
            "values\n", array, len);
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        array[i] = i * 3 + 2;

        // assert() verifies that the given condition is true
        // and exits the program otherwise. This is just a
        // "sanity check" to make sure that the line of code
        // above is doing what we intend.

        assert(array[i] == i * 3 + 2);
    }
    printf("Done!\n");
}

typedef struct {
    int a, b, c, d;
}   FourInts;
```

Below piece of code is written in the main function. I can not understand why the compiler doesn't gives an error or the program stops due to assertion when i cast the heap_fourints pointer as char*.

```
FourInts* heap_fourints=malloc(sizeof(FourInts) * 4);
fillArray( (char*) heap_fourints,4);
assert((*heap_fourints).a == 2);
assert(heap_fourints->b == 5);
assert(heap_fourints->c == 8);
assert(heap_fourints->d == 11);
```

I consider this the right implementation .

```
FourInts* heap_fourints=malloc(sizeof(ints) * 4);
fillArray( (ints*) heap_fourints,4);
assert((*heap_fourints).a == 2);
assert(heap_fourints->b == 5);
assert(heap_fourints->c == 8);
assert(heap_fourints->d == 11);
```

Comment: Why do you expect this code to fail?

Comment: sizeof(char*) == sizeof(int*), this is simple pointer. Why should something break?

Comment: i am a novice.. kindly explain why it shouldn't ?

Comment: The function clearly specifies int * as an input argument.

Comment: @Dima00782: Different pointer types are very commonly the same size, but the language doesn't guarantee it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FourInts* heap_fourints=malloc(sizeof(FourInts) * 4);
```

This will allocate enough memory to hold `4` copies of your structures (each enough to hold 4 integers), which is a memory that is enough for **at least** 16 integers. Though you are not using all of this memory you never read/write beyond it so the run-time is happy (no memory corruption).

OTOH

```
FourInts* heap_fourints=malloc(sizeof(int) * 4); // int, not ints(!)
```

will allocate just enough memory to hold **4 `int`** values. N.B.: this does not *necessarily* mean that this memory is enough to hold the structure with 4 integers due to possible alignment padding (which, however, in case of `int` is not very likely).

But yet again - on your platform you are not violating memory with your second code either.

As for compiler errors, or rather lack of those. `C` is not as strongly typed language as some others (for instance `C++`) and the rules for pointer conversions are somewhat relaxed. A memory pointed to by a variable of one type can be *freely converted* to a different type. This is very dangerous (and is discouraged) though it has its uses, of course. Especially when dealing with extremely low-level code

Comment: Right and in this case char is an integer type in C so the cast is perfectly legal.

Comment: You are right that the standard does not say anything about the size of a struct. However, it says that the size of an array of four `t` has to be `4 * sizeof(t)`, which forces **any** type `t` to contain its own padding if an object of type `t` cannot be accessed with all alignments. For this reason there is absolutely no excuse for a compiler to lay out the four identical members of a struct with any padding. But the standard does not mandate that the compiler does it this way.